# Getting word frequency of a list of sentence, but not combined. (python)

Tags: python

```
def getWordFreq(corpus):

    wordFreq = []
    for sent in corpus:
        for word in sent:
            wordFreq.append((word, sent.count(word)))
    return wordFreq
```

Wrote this function to get a frequency of each word in a corpus.

To test it, I wrote

```
cc = [ ['hi','ho'], ['hee','ho']]
getWordFreq(cc)
```

but this returned

```
[('hi', 1), ('ho', 1), ('hee', 1), ('ho', 1)]
```

instead of ('ho', 2).

What am I missing?

Comment: where `count += 1` (so `count += sent.count(word)`)? last change first value, not addition !

Comment: what did mean with **but not combined**?

Comment: You are counting each word in a `sent` not in the entire `corpus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this simplest one will be helpful. Here we are using `for`.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/868910)

```
def getWordFreq(corpus):
    result = {}
    for data in corpus:
        for word in data:
            if word in result:
                result[word] += 1 #adding result in the dictionary
            else:
                result[word] = 1

    return result.items() #returning items

cc = [['hi', 'ho'], ['hee', 'ho']]
print(getWordFreq(cc))
```

**Output:** `[('hee', 1), ('hi', 1), ('ho', 2)]`

Comment: If you were following this approach, `defaultdict` was much more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution:

```
from collections import Counter
def getWordFreq(corpus):
    wordFreq = [j for i in corpus for j in i]
    return list(Counter(wordFreq).items())
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off using a dictionary for this task:

```
def getWordFrequency(corpus):
    frequencies = {}
    for sentence in corpus:
        for word in sentence:
            if word in frequencies:
                frequencies[word] += 1
            else:
                frequencies[word] = 1
    return frequencies
```

A dictionary preserves a mapping from keys (words) to values (corresponding frequencies). This way, it's easier and faster to keep track of the frequencies, because you don't have to deal with merging words yourself.

Your implementation just adds a tuple consisting of the word and its frequency *in the sentence* to the result. That won't combine words together and keep track of frequencies for you.

Python's `collections` module also provides a `Counter` designed for this type of thing.

```
from collections import Counter
def getWordFrequency(corpus):
    freq = Counter()
    for sentence in corpus:
        for word in sentence:
            freq[word] += 1
    return freq
```

Notice that we don't have to check if the word is already present in the counter, because `Counter` handles it for us.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you are counting each word in a `sent` not in the entire `corpus` Here is what you need to do

```
 def getWordFreq(corpus):
        wordFreq = []
        for sent in corpus:
            for word in sent:
                wordFreq.append((word, sum(map(lambda x: x.count(word), corpus))))
        return wordFreq


cc = [ ['hi','ho'], ['hee','ho']]
getWordFreq(cc)
```

gives

```
[('hi', 1), ('ho', 2), ('hee', 1), ('ho', 2)]
```

If you want to print each word only once, change `wordFreq` to `set` and use `add` instead of `append`

```
def getWordFreq(corpus):

    wordFreq = set()
    for sent in corpus:
        for word in sent:
            wordFreq.add((word, sum(map(lambda x: x.count(word), corpus))))
    return wordFreq

cc = [ ['hi','ho'], ['hee','ho']]
getWordFreq(cc)
```

gives

```
{('hee', 1), ('hi', 1), ('ho', 2)}
```